# C socket server and Python socket client "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, sockets

I am creating a C server and Python client for UNIX domain datagram sockets (UDS) IPC on Ubuntu 18.04.  My scenario is:  Python runs as a child process created with fork-execv where C is the parent process.  The Python client blocks on socket.recvfrom until data is sent by the C server.  When the C server sends data to the Python client then C will block on recvfrom until Python sends data to C with sendto.

I have used UDS for a C client and a C server with no problems, but the C-Python setup is causing some problems.  For this Python version I worked from an example at https://lloydrochester.com/post/c/unix-domain-socket-datagram.

I create a server socket in C and bind to it; it returns file descriptor 5:

```
int64_t * create_socket_server(struct sockaddr_un svaddr, int64_t retvals[])
{
    int sfd, j;
    ssize_t numBytes;
    socklen_t len;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    retvals[0] = 0;
    retvals[1] = 0;

    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); /* Create server socket 

    if (sfd == -1)
         return retvals;

    if (remove(SV_SOCK_PATH) == -1 && errno != ENOENT)
           return retvals;

    memset(&svaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    svaddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(svaddr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH, sizeof(svaddr.sun_path) - 1);

    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1)
           return retvals;

    retvals[0] = sfd;
    retvals[1] = (int64_t)&svaddr;

     return retvals;
}
```

I do not create or explicitly connect to the client socket on the C side.

On the Python side I bind to the client socket.  Here is my Python code, following the example cited, but altered somewhat to fit my use case:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import os, os.path

csock_file = "/tmp/py_sock"
ssock_file = "/tmp/ud_ucase"

if os.path.exists(csock_file):
  os.remove(csock_file)

csock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
csock.bind(csock_file) # Bind to the server socket

return_msg = "Got it"

while True:

    (bytes, address) = csock.recvfrom(720)
    msg = bytes.decode('utf-8')

    print("Python received")

    if msg != "Code_99":
        print('address:',address,'received:',msg)
        csock.sendto(str.encode(return_msg), ssock_file)

    if msg == "Code_99":
        print("closing")
        #Close the socket
```

I want recvfrom to be blocking in both Python and C because Python should block until C sends, but when I leave it at blocking (the default) then Python blocks both processes when it calls (bytes, address) = csock.recvfrom(720), and C cannot continue.

If I set it to nonblocking with csock.setblocking(False) I get this error message:

```
(bytes, address) = csock.recvfrom(720)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

So my question is why does Python block both processes, and why do I get that error message in nonblocking mode?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can set a timeout `socket.settimeout(value)` if there is nothing to receive it will throw socket.error exception and you can use try and catch for that

Comment: Do you know why it blocks both processes in blocking mode?  I thought that only Python would block.

Comment: I don't see the code for sending responses to the client can you share it so I can figure out where is the issue

Comment: At the point where I call (bytes, address) = csock.recvfrom(720) no data has been sent yet, as we have only just connected.  Data will be sent by the server after Python connects and calls recvfrom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

> why does Python block both processes ?

When your client is waiting for your server's response with `recvfrom`, you server just did nothing, thus server blocks at its `recvfrom` as well.

> why do I get that error message in nonblocking mode ?

Your server/client might not be as robust as the one you quoted (i.e. from *lloydrochester.com*). Serveral parts broke and result in breaking the whole thing. Some of them are just about C Lang, such as *Variable Declarations*, *Function Returning*, etc. Others are about network programming, such as *Buffer Sizing*, *Socket Internals*, etc. It's not realistic to list them all and analyse one by one. Better read through [K&R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) and [BSD socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) to fix them thoroughly.

However, here is an relatively simple implementation for you case, based on your codes, shown below. In addition, you might want to change the reply message to `Code_99` in the 48th line of *server_alice.c*.

---

##### Environment

```
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc 7.5.0
Python 3.6.9
```

##### server_alice.c

```c
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 720
#define SV_SOCK_PATH "ssock"
int create_socket_server(int *sfd_ptr, struct sockaddr_un *svaddr_ptr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct sockaddr_un svaddr, claddr;
    int sfd, j;
    ssize_t numBytes;
    socklen_t len;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    int64_t retvals[2];

    if (create_socket_server(&sfd, &svaddr) == 0)
        printf("create_socket_server...DONE\n");
    else exit(0);

    for (;;) {
        len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        printf("waiting clients...\n");
        numBytes = recvfrom(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &claddr, &len);

        if (numBytes == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error recvfrom");
            return 4;
        }
        claddr.sun_path[len - sizeof(sa_family_t) - 1] = 0;
        buf[numBytes] = '\0';
        fprintf(stdout, "server received %ld bytes from %s, they are: \x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m\n", (long) numBytes,
                claddr.sun_path, buf);

        for (j = 0; j < numBytes; j++) {
            buf[j] = toupper((unsigned char) buf[j]);
        }

        // char *reply_msg="Code_99";        #   different reply message
        char *reply_msg = "Hello Bob~ This is a message: blablablabla";

        j = sendto(sfd, reply_msg, strlen(reply_msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &claddr, len);
        if (j != strlen(reply_msg)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error sendto %s", strerror(errno));
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/* Your create_socket_server, with a few changes */
int create_socket_server(int *sfd_ptr, struct sockaddr_un *svaddr_ptr) {
    struct sockaddr_un svaddr;
    int sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // Create server socket

    if (sfd == -1)
        return -1;

    if (remove(SV_SOCK_PATH) == -1 && errno != ENOENT)
        return -1;

    memset(&svaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    svaddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(svaddr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH, sizeof(svaddr.sun_path) - 1);
    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1)
        return -1;

    memcpy(sfd_ptr, &sfd, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(svaddr_ptr, &svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));


    return 0;
}
```

##### client_bob.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import os, os.path

csock_file = "./csock"
ssock_file = "./ssock"

if os.path.exists(csock_file):
    os.remove(csock_file)

csock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
csock.bind(csock_file)  # Bind to the server socket

return_msg = "Got it"
csock.sendto(str.encode("Hello Alice! I'm coming!"), ssock_file)
# while True:     #       ! CATION !       If 'while(true)', there will be infinite message sending back and forth!
(bytes, address) = csock.recvfrom(720)
msg = bytes.decode('utf-8')

if msg != "Code_99":
    print('address:    ', address, 'received:   ', msg)
    csock.sendto(str.encode(return_msg), ssock_file)

if msg == "Code_99":
    print("closing")
    csock.close()
```

##### Server Output:

```
$ gcc server_alice.c && ./a.out
create_socket_server...DONE
waiting clients...
server received 24 bytes from ./csock, they are: Hello Alice! I'm coming!
waiting clients...
server received 6 bytes from ./csock, they are: Got it
waiting clients...
```

##### Client Output:

```
$ python3 client_bob.py 
address:     ssock received:    Hello Bob~ This is a message: blablablabla
```

Comment: Michael - in the line "numBytes = recvfrom(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &claddr, &len);" you haven't identified &claddr.  How does this program know the claddr structure with just a pointer?

Comment: @RTC222 This is a quite common way for setting value of variables, which is accomplished by memory operations, say [memcpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html). You can see they occurr in many built-in C library functions. Or you can try this small piece of codes: `void set_val_using_ptr(int *i_need_new_val){
    int new_val=567;
    memcpy(i_need_val, &new_val, sizeof(int));
}`, might give you an rather intuitive explanation.